# Searching for a python package reading excel and not auto formating its raw values

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

I encountered with several python packages which auto convert date strings values in cells to `datetime` representation automatically upon loading the excel with the package, can you point me to several packages which have a control over auto conversion of values when loading worksheet.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [xlrd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) reads the date as a number by default. However you can always convert it to a Python datetime via xlrd's `xldate_as_tuple` function.

See the following links for more information:

- http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html
- http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.xldate_as_tuple-function

**Update**: Let's say I create an Excel spreadsheet and the first value I enter is `12/13/2014` in row 1, col 1. Next, I enter `'9/1/2015 15:30:15'` in row 2, col 1. I save this file as `test.xls` and open up Python in my terminal and enter the following:

```
>>> import xlrd
>>> wb = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xls')
>>> sheet1 = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
>>> col_vals = sheet1.col_values(0)
>>> col_vals
[41986.0, u"9/1/2015 15:30:15'"]
```

You will note that the first date I entered is read as a float, exactly as the xlrd documentation said it would. The second value is a unicode string because I put single quotes around it when I entered it into Excel. Thus, Excel never saved it as a date, but as a string.

**In conclusion**, if you are careful to enter your dates in Excel as strings, then `xlrd` will happily read them as strings. But if you enter them as actual dates, the `xlrd` will read them in the format that Excel save them in, which are floats.

Comment: I need to read it as string, its date and time

Comment: I'm already using openpyxl, but quite puzzled how can I disable its auto conversion

Comment: The problem is that Excel stores dates as floats, it just displays a string to the user. So when `xlrd` reads it, we get a float. This is why you may need to use the `xldate_as_tuple` to turn that into a Python `datetime` object which you can then format to match what Excel is doing.

Comment: I'm not sure you got me, I have string representing date in excel cell: could be `9/1/2015 15:30:15`

Comment: I need to get this as string no datetime, I may do parsing using `datetime.strptime` myself later on

Comment: This answer is basically correct, but is a little fuzzy where it doesn't need to be. xlrd is not limited to reading .xls files. It handles .xlsx just fine. And Excel doesn't "typically" save dates as floats, it *always* saves dates as floats.

Comment: Admittedly I haven't used xlrd for quite a while. I know when I first used it, xlrd did not support xlsx. Anyway, I updated the answer to remove the fuzzy stuff.